# How get rid of displayed external 'bones' in binary FBX character, imported from MakeHuman?

Tags: .fbx, makehuman

[image: After import FBX in object mode]

I see many external bones around an imported binary FBX file, made in MakeHuman. The view in Pose mode is also very difficult to work with. How can I change the view, so that I only see the rig?

Answer (score 0):

I don´t think the problem is the view or external bones. After import a fbx, the armature and meshes must be aligned and the lengths of the bones reduced for a better overview. The following script should do that for you. Open a new text block in workspace Scripting. Rename 'text' to 'text.py' and copy the code with RMB into it. Select your armature and press run.

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT') 
obj = bpy.context.object              
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')              
bpy.data.objects[obj.name].select_set(True) 
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
bpy.ops.pose.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.pose.armature_apply(selected=False)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT') 
obj = bpy.context.object 
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=True, rotation=True, scale=True)            
bpy.data.objects[obj.name].select_set(False)            
for mesh in bpy.data.objects:
    if mesh.parent == obj:
        mesh.select_set(True)
        mesh.rotation_euler[0] += -1.5708               
        bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=True, rotation=True, scale=True)                
        mesh.select_set(False)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
obj = bpy.context.object              
ebones = obj.data.edit_bones  
change = 0
for bone in ebones:    
    if bone.name == "root":
        for idx in range(3):
            ebones['root'].tail[idx] =  ebones['spine05'].head[idx]                   
    if bone.name == "head":
        change = 1
    if bone.name == "pelvis.L":
        change = 0                
    if change == 1:
        bone.length = 0.05
obj.show_in_front = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply and advise.
I did my best to follow it up in an Blender text block, renamed as text.py
Then save, and reload the fbx-file. But I see still the same result.

I discovered lately however, that fbx binary files made in Mixamo are displaying fine.
So I think that's is the most simple in between solution for me as a noob in scripting an related abstract subjects.
Anyway, thanks!